# Available code flash space on S1 series of Renesas Synergy?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm evaluating the Renesas Synergy platform. Does anyone know the available code flash space on the S1 series (ultra low power)?
Thx!

Comment: please use this site to fix your program errors, not other people to create them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Typing what I just did into Google would have been far quicker than you actually asking this question:

[Renesas S1 Series](https://www.renesas.com/en-eu/products/synergy/microcontrollers/s1-series.html)